# why in sabreR library if i running multivariate linear mixed models with three models thats found error

Tags: r

in the library SabreR, i found error of i use multivariate linear mixed models with three model. but if i use only two models, that can run. please help me to fix it.. thank you

```
 model1 = formula(Y1_Mat ~ 1 + as.factor(X1)+ as.factor(X2))
 model2 = formula(Y2_Sains ~ 1+ as.factor(X1) + factor(X2))
 model3 = formula(Y3_Baca ~ 1+ as.factor(X1) + factor(X2))

mixedmodels = sabre(model.formula.uni = model1,
                model.formula.bi = model2,
                model.formula.tri = model3,
                first.family = "gaussian",
                second.family = "gaussian",
                third.family = "gaussian",
                arithmetic.type = "fast",
                case = list(c(Kode_Sekolah)),
                correlated = "yes",
                adaptive.quad = TRUE,
                first.mass = 12,second.mass = 12,third.mass = 12)
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Can you please post a [mcve]? (For other potential answerers, sabreR is archived on CRAN since 2013: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sabreR/index.html)

Comment: that's found error "Error in parameter.match[2]:(prompt.match[prompt.match > parameter.match[2]][1] -  : 
  NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
2: In sabre.fit(sabre.instance, sabre.binary = sabre.binary, script.file = script.file,  :
  passing a char vector to .Fortran is not portable"